# Can we get the UAC prompt to show only once?

Tags: .net, windows-7, uac

Is there a way for an app to present the user with the UAC prompt only once, upon first running. Thereafter, no further prompting.

In other words, I understand that our app needs the user's UAC permission to do certain things. And that's fine. But we don't want it to have to keep asking on every occasion it runs. Can the user give permission to our app for all time? Or does what I am asking violate the fundamentals of UAC?

We are working with .NET and Windows 7

Comment: Are you using Vista or Windows 7?

Comment: Windows 7, if the solutions works in Vista too then that's a bonus

Comment: Can you give some examples of the things your software does that requires administrative access? i'm just curious to know. It's hard to come up with any scenario's where some of our software require it.

Comment: we are accessing the Volume Shadow Copy

Comment: just seen your overview/answer below. looks good

Answer (score 15):

The answer to your question is: *No, you cannot do that.*

---

Microsoft specifically is forbidding such behavior. If a applications could add themselves to an exclude list, then we get back into the mess we had before.

What you need to do is make your program not require administrative access.

Ask yourself: **What did you do on Windows XP?**

- am i not allowed to run your software?
- does your software crash when i'm a standard user?
- does your software provide no value, and have no absolutely no functionality when run by a standard user?

Windows XP doesn't have the convince of the UAC. The only way for a user to run your program as an administrator is to logon with another user. And that's a much worse user experience than clicking "Continue".

If you don't want to write software that is standard user friendly, then you're part of the problem. UAC is not the problem, UAC is a convience. i can turn off UAC, run as a standard user full time, and your software **still** won't work.

---

[Microsoft considered](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/UAC-What-How-Why/)

- white-lists
- *Remember my preference*
- *Don't ask me again.*

If you had a white-list, then every program would just add itself to such a list at install time.

If such a white-list existed, then your app would be the target of malware. It would love to modify the binary to execute what it wants; since it knows the program will be silently elevated.

Malware would love to poke at your application with SendMessage, trying to pass invalid data or structures, trying to get your, administrative, application to execute the code it wants.

If the user had the option to disable future prompts on programs, then they would just do it, and every program would run as an administrator, and we'll be back to the way things were.

All those ideas don't solve the problem: almost **no program actually requires administrative access**.

The time has finally come to force developers to come to terms with that fact.

---

### Whitelists cannot work

Some people want to come up with ways to make whitelists work.

- *Have a checkbox where the user can say, "Don't prompt me for this file anymore"*
  If you store that filename, then other programs with the same name will silently run as administrators.
- *Okay, then we'll record the full path, or use the hash of the file, as the whitelist entry.*
  If there's a whitelist then other programs will add themselves to that list when they install, and have programs running with administrative access that the user didn't want.
- *What if only signed applications are allowed, that way we know they're safe.* Applications are not safe because they're signed. An application doesn't have to be malware for it to be abused into doing bad things. (e.g. buffer overruns in flash, firefox, ie, chrome, safari, opera, word, photoshop, Yahoo image uploader tool).

You have to store list of valid code-signers in a list **somehwere**. And no matter how you slice it, having **any** white-list will mean that applications will just add themselves to that list.

- *Well, then don't allow them access to the list. Not even administrators are allowed to add items to the list.*  If not even administrators can add items to the list, then how can the user add items to the list in the first place? You can't add items to the whitelist if you're not allowed to add items to the whitelist!

And how do you manage the white-list? Lets say the user has changed their mind, or Dad has changed his mind, or IT has changed its mind, or corporate has changed its mind, or the software publisher changes their mind: how do you remove items from the list - especially when nobody is allowd to modify the list.

Summary: **White lists cannot work**.

Comment: This is a simple and on the perhaps on the surface unfriendly seeming approach, but it may be quite correct. While there maybe a good reason your app needs elevated permissions in many cases it's just because the application doesn't follow best practices and is badly written to begin with. In most scenarios (e.g. auto-updating) it's very rare to need elevated permissions so it's not a burden on users to trigger then when actually needed. If your app needs them every time the design is /probably/ flawed.

Comment: Just to correct an incorrect assertion - you can indeed elevate permissions in Windows XP as well, in a very similar way to Vista/Windows 7 - unfortunately most developers were too lazy to bother and just insisted everyone run their applications with Administrator accounts.

Comment: You could, Iain, **RunAs** another user in Windows XP. But then the process isn't actually running at you. In Vista and 7 the process is actually running as yourself.

Comment: +1 for a nice overview but I'm not sure saving the user from having to reclick and reclick is any defence against malware. if the user is accepting the UAC prompt anyway (and he will), I'm just as inviting a target for malware as if the UAC preference was being remembered. Whether Remembered or Actively Renewed, the result is the same. But the difference in convenience to the user is enormous.

Comment: and doesnt digital signing come into it?

Comment: @hawbsl: Users should not have to reclick and reclick. The point is to smack developers in the back of the head, and make them not actually require administrative access. There's almost no reason that you actually do. Once the software ecosystem as a whole makes administrative access rare, then the user will be presented with a UAC prompt very rarely. Then they will see administrative access for what it is: something dangerous, not to be granted lightly. The next 7 years will be the painful transition period, where developers get bitched out for being lazy.

Comment: @hawbsl: Digitally signed executables changed the color (and phrasing) of the UAC prompt (Blue for signed Windows executables, gray for signed non-Windows executables, yellow for unsigned executables, red for executables signed with a revoked digital certificate)

Comment: Why couldn't whitelists work if it contained application signatures, and the only ways to get on the whitelist required UAC prompts?  I don't see why whitelisted programs would be more of an attack vector for buffer attacks etc. than would be programs that users are simply going to click "OK" for.

Comment: @supercat Whitelists wouldn't work because programs would add themselves to the whitelist during install. (Remember installers run with administrative permissions).

Comment: @Ian Boyd: Why could not the UAC prompt include a list of programs that an application would want to add to the whitelist, and only permit those which had been explicitly listed to be added?  Actually, a somewhat-detailed permissions whitelist would seem much friendlier and more secure than what UAC provides now.  For example, if an application knows it's only going to save files with certain extensions, its whitelist could say so; even if malware took over the application got taken using a buffer overflow or other such exploit, the malware would...

Comment: ...be limited to creating files with the extensions authorized by the original application.  Things could be further improved by having the file-open/file-save dialogs interact with the white-list manager, so that the only file paths the application could do anything with would be those that a user had selected via the file-open dialog (or config-files that were explicitly listed in the manifest).  There are many reasons a program should need privileges beyond the minimum available, but there's no reason a common application should need full admin privileges.  Why can't...

Comment: ...programs simply be given the actual privileges they need?  UAC would be much more useful then: "This program wants permission to access the USB scanner, and it wants permission load and save files of system-defined graphics-file types, in all non-protected directories."

Comment: @supercat Where are you going to store this whitelist so that installer programs cannot add themselves to it? A file? The registry?

Comment: @Ian Boyd: I'd suggest a tree of whitelists; the whitelists associated with programs in a directory could be stored in that directory, but would only be acknowledged as valid if their hash matched a value stored in a higher-level whitelist.  Higher-level whitelists would be digitally signed by a system secret key.  For this to work, of course, it would be necessary to severely limit what programs had truly unlimited access to the system, but that's equally true of UAC.

Comment: First, properly implemented white list could work. Your argument assumes that MS would leave it lying around like the registry. Tie the thing to directly to the "Oh please never again with this insanity!" check box on the UAC form and forget about it. There is no reason that every application running as Administrator would have to have write access to the thing. Secondly, the default file installation is Program Files, so you install there, then go to update your application and... so either MS screwed up the default install location, the UAC defaults, or the User experience. Choose one.

Comment: @Joshua Drake *"Your argument assumes that MS would leave it lying around"* Name *any* other place it could be put. You keep skipping this point, like it's a minor implementation detail.  *"There is no reason that every application running as Administrator would have to have write access to the thing."* There is reason why every application running as Administrator would have write access to the thing - they are an administrator. Either they have power to administer the machine or they don't. Sounds like you're proposing some sort of "Power User" security level. But then how do i run as admin?

Comment: @Joshua Drake You also keep forgetting the easy answer: What des you app do under Windows XP when i'm running as a standard user? What do you do on Windows Vista or Windows 7 when i'm running as a standard user with UAC turned off? Does your application refuse to run? Does it crash? Does it give errors? Does your application need to run as administrator? UAC is a *convenience* added with Windows Vista - if i don't like it i'm free to turn it off. But then i'm a standard user with no way to elevate; i have to *Fast User Switch* to an administrator account. That's a bad user experience.

Comment: @Ian Boyd - The system, even back to Windows NT could do things that I couldn't do as the Admin.  The Right to logon as service comes to mind.  In XP an auto update app just copies the files into Program Files, I know because the same app does so today. It is only Windows 7 that has this issue.  I don't know what to tell you, we have another application doing the same thing for our CR reps under XP, who certainly are not Admins on the Domain, or even their own machines.  Windows Vista bit the dust on the same app, so don't go around acting like XP encounters the same issues as Windows 7.

Comment: @Joshua Drake: It is trivial programmatically to get to "system" privileges if you are an administrator user, thus your point is moot.

Comment: The answer to your question **is**, "*No, you cannot do that.*" You can hate it, think it's stupid, wish it wasn't so - but it's still the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Oops I originally misread the question and interpreted it as "prompt only once, on the very first run" instead of "only once every, every time it's run" (edited accordingly below).

You can't grant an application Administrator rights for all time, that does indeed go against the design of UAC.

However, one way around this is to create a service which your app communicates with, which is able to run in the background and perform tasks with elevated permissions without the main application needing elevated permissions.

A service will only need to prompt once, when it is installed.

If that sounds like too much work, you could have a look at bundling with the SkipUAC utility which uses an approach like this to allow users to start applications without being prompted for UAC on each startup.

**My Original Answer:**

If the executable has a manifest with requireAdministrator set it should trigger a UAC prompt only on each initial startup, but not after that (i.e. all operations, including other apps launched by the initial process will inherit the elevated permissions, but if you quit the application and start it again the prompt will once again appear).

You can set up a manifest for an EXE via the IDE in Visual Studio 2008/2010, or using a command line utility that comes with the most recent service pack for VS 2005 (this can be integrated into the build step to automate the process, but is a bit of a fudge in 2005).

I would search the web for "UAC" and "manifest" for more information, it's reasonably well documented in the online MSDN documentation (once know you to look for it).

This works equally in Windows 7 and Windows Vista.

Comment: but can the user give permission to our app for all time? so the UAC never appears on subsequent executions?

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to install yourself as a service or device driver.

Comment: There is the concept of having some elevated processing running all the time, and the user can communicate with it. But we weary, malware will love to poke at your service to make it execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help:

http://www.tipandtrick.net/2008/bypass-or-disable-uac-for-selected-excluded-programs-only-with-elevator-skipuac/

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible (I dont think it is considering say [How to configure Visual Studio not to give UAC prompt on each run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451809/how-to-configure-visual-studio-not-to-give-uac-prompt-on-each-run)), I'm pretty sure it has to be done on the users side (like disabling the prompt in the first place), rather than the application side.

Comment: Oops, please ignore what I just wrote, I misread the question.

Answer (score -2):

The user should be able to right-click on the executable and go to properties -> compatibility -> "run this program as administrator’"

Comment: Does it not still give the UAC prompt? I thought this was mainly to fix legacy apps crashing that did  something requiring admin rights, but didn't ask for those rights before doing it?

Comment: @Fire Lancer Yes, many program would crash on Windows XP if the user was not an administrator. Rather than "Run as Administrator" every time, you could just check the box.

Comment: This still gives the prompt.  The only way to get rid of the prompt is to specifically turn it off in the Security settings.