# Change ip settings(default gateway) in C# without admin privileges

Tags: c#, networking, admin

I'm currently trying to edit Windows Network settings through C# code in my app and I can't seem to figure out a way to do it the "right" way? Specifically I'm trying to remove the default gateway for the ethernet interface. Our app works in conjunction with a mini-router through LAN cable, and the only way to allow internet access through the wifi gateway is to remove the mini-router gateway.

I've tried calling external utilities...

Editing the table directly:

```
route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <gateway of real internet>
```

Editing Windows Network Settings:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address "Ethernet" static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0 none
```

But I figured it would be better to do it directly through code so now I have:

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
   if (mo["Description"].Equals(ethernetInterfaceDesc))
   {
      mo.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", new object[] {
         new string[] { ethernetInterfaceIp },
         new string[] { "255.255.255.0" }
      });

      mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", new object[] {
         new string[] { null },
         new string[] { "1" }
      });

      Log.debug("Set gateway for " + mo["Description"]);
      break;
   }
}
```

In all cases I reverted the changes I made with similar actions upon closing of the app, and I retrieved the interface name and ip programmatically.

All of these worked perfectly, but the problem is that the app has to run elevated or ask the user for admin access at certain points. And after reading this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022387/3112658 I feel like there HAS to be another way. Thanks.

Comment: Can you do it from the command line or a GUI app without elevation? If not, what makes you think you can do it from a C# program without requesting elevation?