# Why does the IIS application require elevated permissions to attach to?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

I'm having this exact problem:

[Visual Studio requires elevated permissions in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745085/visual-studio-requires-elevated-permissions-in-windows-7)

But I'm not really happy with any of the answers there so I was wondering if someone could expand on an alternative solution.

## Setup

- dev box is running server 2008
- Visual Studio 2010
- IIS 7

In order to attach to a process running under IIS, I am being told I need to run Visual Studio as an administrator. If I do this, whenever I edit and check a file into source control the other users (who are not administrators) can't edit the file because the FILE now needs elevated permissions to edit! Causing massive headaches, so basically running VS as admin doesn't appear to be an option.

Does anyone have any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Attaching to process which runs under different user credentials or higher integrity level requires SE_DEBUG privilege which application obtains when running as administrator. Your IIS AppPool is most likely not configured to run under your account hence the requirement for elevated permissions.

Starting from Windows Vista SE_DEBUG privilege is disabled for processes not running as admin (or more precisely, not running with high integrity level).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx):

> Certain administrative Windows privileges can be assigned to an access
>   token only with at least a high integrity level. If the access token
>   integrity level is less than high, then specific administrative
>   privileges are not allowed and are removed from the access token. The
>   administrative privileges associated with a high integrity level are:
>
> ...
>
> SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE
>   ...

And fruther from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee695867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> SeDebugPrivilege  - Required to debug and adjust the memory of a
>   process owned by another account. User Right: Debug programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to properties on your website project, then click on the 'web' tab, then choose the option 'Use local iis web server', you can then debug 'as normal'. That works for us without elevated permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Trying to change that setting results in "To access web sites on the local IIS web server, you must run visual studio under an administrator account"

Answer (score 1):

Bit late in the game here, but I've found if you install [Remote Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40781) and install it locally, you can then attach to `w3wp.exe` without having to run under elevated permissions!

Answer (score 1):

> To give this privilege
>
> 1)      Run GPEDIT.MSC from command prompt.
>
> 2)      Navigate to
>
> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings ->
>   Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Right Assignment -> Debug
>   programs and add users to it.*
>
> *You should also be aware of If you grant somebody SeDebugPrivilege, you gave away the farm

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f394922-4d3d-4c00-8bc1-88aeeeedd843/how-to-add-a-user-to-debug-users-group?forum=netfxbcl

**Update**:

This not works too.

The alternative is, as describe on book "Professional Visual Basic 2012 and .NET 4.5 Programming": Go to the bin/debug folder and manually start the ProVB2012_Security.exe executable outside of debugger. But in either case you should now be prompted to grant administrator rights...